# Div with css animation behind displays peculiarly in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, z-index

I have a problem with a form being displayed peculiarly in chrome(only in chrome, works in FF and safari).

Basically, the form is on top of the rotating div, with a z-index:2 and the animation behind has z-index:1

When I give the form a higher z-index, the radio buttons suddenly have a white square behind them, just like a background-color, except that there isn't any. Also, the text-shadow which is supposed to be black is turned white. I haven't been able to eliminate these effects and have no idea why this happens.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Page is here:
http://fatdogcs.com/rdv/index-test.html

This is how it looks like in Chrome: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8974822/test.jpg

Css code for the wheel rotation:

```
#Wheel{
    background-image:url(../images/circle.png);

    -webkit-animation: rotateWheel 60s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:    rotateWheel 60s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation:     rotateWheel 60s linear infinite;

    height:370px;
    width:370px;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 195px;
    left: 315px;
    z-index: 1; 
}
```

Css code for the form div:

```
#Over18Form{
    width:  225px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 387px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Html code is:

```
    <div id="Wheel"></div>
    <div id="Over18Form">
        <form>
            <div id="Over18"></div>
            <input type="radio" name="age" id="Yes" />
            <label for="Yes" style="margin-right:10px;">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="age" id="No" />
            <label for="No">No</label>

            <div id="ChooseLanguage"></div>
            <input type="radio" name="language" id="English" />
            <label for="English" style="margin-right:10px;">English</label>
            <input type="radio" name="language" id="Chinese" />
            <label for="Chinese">中文</label>
            <div class="clear" style="margin-bottom:30px;"></div>
            <button type="submit">Enter</button> 
        </form>
```

Comment: I can't see your problem, it works fine for me in chrome

Comment: Looks exactly the same in Chrome and FF for me. However, I don't see any z-index mentioned in the CSS or inline: did you link to the correct page? If you did, can you put some of the suspected code in the Q?

Comment: this is how it looks on my comp in chrome:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8974822/test.jpg

Comment: its fine in mine also. What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: i confirm the problem in chrome 15.0.874.121 - pretty strange, if you remove the wheel div the problem is gone...

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things, when I removed -webkit-animation: rotateWheel 60s linear infinite; it looked ok.

I would suggest:
1)Using JavaScript to rotate the wheel, try this plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/
2) Or just use your own radio buttons via image as png-24

(I had a similar problem when combining borders, divs and -webkit-border-raidus with different z-index animations.)